# Carousel Image loading.like gallery-react-native-snap-carousel-v4'

Tags: reactjs

am using more than 200 images sometimes the images not loading.kindly help me to found the solution.

Sometimes the images not loading it shows blank screen.

````
Using : react-native-snap-carousel-v4' npm.
<Carousel
marginTop={-60}
layout={'default'}
zIndex={-10}
height={'70%'}
data={imageUrls}
initialNumToRender={imageUrls.length}
maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
ref={isCarousel}
sliderWidth={state.viewport.width}
itemWidth={state.viewport.width}
firstItem={index}
useScrollView={true}
enableSnap={true}
onScrollIndexChanged={setCurrentIndex}
activeSlideAlignment="center"
renderItem={({item, index}) => (
<Image
key={index}
style={{
width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
}}
resizeMode="contain"
source={{uri: item.uri}}
onLoadEnd={() => {setisImageLoaded(false);}}
/>
)}
/>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DwN.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys7PU.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
removeClippedSubviews={true}
```

enable this option carousel it will load pretty.